# word length in mnemonic phrase

Tags: wallets

What is the standard length of words in the mnemonic phrase for various ethereum wallets ? I need to know this in order to decide what should be the choices given to the user while creating a ethereum wallet address by using bip39 library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want to dig into what the standard specifies.

Dumb counts of the (English) word list from the [Bitcoin BIP repo](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0039/bip-0039-wordlists.md) below:

```
import urllib
from collections import Counter

url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bitcoin/bips/master/bip-0039/english.txt"
lines = urllib.urlopen(url).readlines()

counts = Counter([len(line) for line in lines])
for i, j in sorted(counts.items()):
    print("Words of length %d: %d" % (i, j))
```

Output:

```
Words of length 4: 103
Words of length 5: 442
Words of length 6: 555
Words of length 7: 508
Words of length 8: 352
Words of length 9: 88
```

Comment: It's worth noting that (iirc) the first 4 letters of each word are unique, so in theory you only have to store the first 4 letters + word list in order to recover your accounts protected by the mnemonic phrase. I'm recalling from memory tho.

Comment: Good point - I think I new this, but had probably forgotten :-) (This is an interesting read: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/49140/what-is-a-mnemonic-frequency-analysis-and-why-do-i-only-need-4-letters-of-my-see)